# Compact Java Externalization

Tags: java, serialization

I am trying to figure out a way to serialize simple Java objects (ie all the fields are primitive types) compactly, without the big header that normally gets added on when you use writeExternal. It does not need to be super general, backwards compatible across versions, or anything like that, I just want it to work with ObjectOutputStreams (or something similar) and not add ~100 bytes to the size of each object I serialize.

More concretely, I have a class that has 3 members: a boolean flag and two longs. I should be able to represent this object in 17 bytes. Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
class Record implements Externalizable {
    bool b;
    long id;
    long uid;

    public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput out) throws IOException {
        int size = 1 + 8 + 8; //I know, I know, but there's no sizeof
        ByteBuffer buff = ByteBuffer.allocate(size);
        if (b) {
            buff.put((byte) 1);
        } else {
            buff.put((byte) 0);
        }
        buff.putLong(id);
        buff.putLong(uid);
        out.write(buff.array(), 0, size);
    }
}
```

Elsewhere, these are stored by being passed into a method like the following:

```
public void store(Object value) throws IOException {
    ObjectOutputStream out = getStream();
    out.writeObject(value);
    out.close();
}
```

After I store just one of these objects in a file this way, the file has a size of 128 bytes (and 256 for two of them, so it's not amortized). Looking at the file, it is clear that it is writing in a header similar to the one used in default serialization (which, for the record, uses about 376 bytes to store one of these). I can see that my writeExternal method is getting invoked (I put in some logging), so that isn't the problem. Is this just a fundamental limitation of the way ObjectOutputStream deserializes things? Do I need to work on raw DataOutputStreams to get the kind of compactness I want?

[EDIT: In case anyone is wondering, I ended up using DataOutputStreams directly, which turned out to be easier than I'd feared]

Comment: Built in serialization does bloat out your messages. DataOutputStreams is one way, but there are also many other libraries. For example, Google's protocol buffers... https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial

Comment: You don't need the `ByteBuffer` here. The `ObjectOutput` interface supports `writeLong()` and friends.

Comment: And I don't know what the `if (buff)` test is for. It doesn't even compile.

Comment: ^I was worried it would put the big header in front of each field if I used those, I'll try that though, it will at least be a little simpler that way. And ya my bad, that should be if (b)

Comment: Also, thanks @Bret, protobuffs would do the trick, but unfortunately this is for a school project and they want us to implement everything ourselves using only standard java libs